# How to use static resources for automatic DataTemplate resolution in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

I have

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fruit}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Apple">
            <TextBlock Text="This is an apple"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Orange">
            <TextBlock Text="This is an orange"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Potato">
            <TextBlock Text="Lets assume potato is a fruit"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

where Fruit is

```
ObservableCollection<IFruit> Fruit = new Observable Collection<IFruit>();
public class Apple:IFruit{ }
public class Orange:IFruit{ }
public class Potato:IFruit{ }
```

This works fine. But since all of the seperate Fruit markups are quite large, I'd rather move their `DataTemplate`s to their own `ResourceDictionary`ies in seperate files.
What I am trying to do is

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fruit}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="AppleDataTemplate" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="OrangeDataTemplate" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PotatoDataTemplate" />
    </ListView.Resources>
```

where DataTemplates are

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AppleDataTemplate" DataType="Apple">
        <TextBlock Text="This is an apple"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but this throws

```
{"'XAML Node Stream: Value of 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' must follow a StartObject and StartMember.' Line number '130' and line position '18'."}
```

Where `Line number '130'` is the `<StaticResource>` element.

My question then is how does one use static resources for automatic DataTemplate resolution in a ListView?

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513983(v=vs.110).aspx), shouldn't the `StartObject` and `StartMember` be implicit for those elements? Similar to how  `<Party.Favors>` is defined in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge those `DataTemplate` `ResourceDictionary`s into `ListView.Resources` by doing:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fruit}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="AppleTemplate.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="OrangeTemplate.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="PotatoTemplate.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Then, the `DataTemplate`s will be available to `ListView`. Alternatively, you can merge these `ResourceDictionary`s at a higher level (i.e. the `UserControl` XAML file where you have your `ListView` defined).

You may want to remove `x:Key` from your `DataTemplate` definitions in `ResourceDictionary`s.